# Neo4j - Load CSV with Sequence Relationship

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, cypher

I am planning to load train schedule and stations into Neo4j from CSV.

Source Data

```
TrainNo TrainName   SEQ   StationCode   Arrival Departure Distance
1           TN_1          1      S1           8      9       0
1           TN_1          2      S2           10     11     10
1           TN_1          3      S3           12     1      15 
1           TN_1          4      S4           3      4       15
2           TN_2          1      S1         
2           TN_2          2      S2         
2           TN_2          3      S5         
2           TN_2          4      S6         
2           TN_2          5      S7         
2           TN_2          6      S8
```

I need to build nodes and relationship like this

```
S1--(TrainNo,TrainName,SEQ,Arrival,Depature,Distance)--S2--(TrainNo,TrainName,SEQ,Arrival,Depature,Distance)--S3--(TrainNo,TrainName,SEQ,Arrival,Depature,Distance)-S4
```

Basically, the TrainNo, TrainName,Seq, Arrival, Depature and Distance will be on the relationships, and the same relationships will form a route between the stations.

Neo4j - 3.5

Comment: I have loaded all the StationCode using MERGE, so that there is no Duplicate stationcode. Also in my past experience, I have loaded data like From and To columns. I haven;t loaded anything with sequences

Comment: This is a very odd CSV. Normally you would have something like a relationship CSV where each row represents a relationship you want to create (assuming all nodes are already created) so the CSV should have something like `TrainNo, TrainName, SEQ, StationCodeFrom, StationCodeTo, Arrival, Departure, Distance`. That way all rows are independent from each other. With your current structure, rows are dependent upon other rows, so for example by looking only at row 1 there is no way to tell what the To station is, it requires information from other rows. If you can please create a better CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort and group by train and sequence (assuming the file is called `train.csv`)

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///train.csv" AS row
WITH row ORDER BY row.TrainNo, row.SEQ
WITH row.TrainNo AS TrainNo, collect(row) AS stations
UNWIND range(0, size(stations) - 2) AS idx
WITH TrainNo, stations[idx] AS start, stations[idx+1] AS end
MERGE (s1:Station {code:start.StationCode})
MERGE (s2:Station {code:end.StationCode})
// depends on your model (see below)
CREATE (s1)-[:ROUTE {train:TrainNo}]->(s2);

// alternative
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///train.csv" AS row
WITH row ORDER BY row.TrainNo, row.SEQ
MERGE (t:Train {trainNo: row.TrainNo})
WITH row.TrainNo AS TrainNo, collect(row) AS stations
UNWIND range(0, size(stations) - 2) AS idx
WITH TrainNo, stations[idx] AS begin, stations[idx+1] AS last
MERGE (s1:Station {code:begin.StationCode})
MERGE (s2:Station {code:last.StationCode})
CREATE (s1)-[:LEAVES]->(l:Leg)-[:ENTERS]->(s2)
CREATE (l)-[:OF_TRAIN]->(t)
```